# Find center of mass and moment applied on beam structure.

Tags: calculus

I have a simple mathematical problem to solve but it is giving me a slightly difficult time to figure out. The problem:

I have a beam structure with same cross section. It consists of three beam. First in vertical with length 1meter. Second beam joined on top with a angle of 20degrees to the right with lenth 1.1meter and on top of the second beam, a third beam parallel to the ground with 1meter length.

I need to find the center of gravity and how much moment i have on the base of the structure so I would add a mass that would be sufficient to avoid the structure to fall over.

any ideas how?

thanks

Comment: I think Physics.SE is a better fit. Do make the question more precise! The third beam in particular can be parallel to the ground in infinitely many direction. For example, it could be in the plane determined by the two first beams (idealized as line segments). Or it could be perpendicular to that plane.